# Create data list to pass to FFT with AdioGraph UWP

Tags: c#, audio, uwp, fft

I have to pass the data to the fft method that will calculate the spectrum. I tried think incorrectly. I need to understand how to pass the data correctly.

How can I know that the three main groups of frequencies are present: low, medium and high?

Code:

```
List<double> List_db_For_FFT = new List<double>();
int Number_Of_db_List = 0;

private void AudioGraph_QuantumProcessed(AudioGraph sender, object args)
{
    AudioFrame frame = frameOutputNode.GetFrame();
    ProcessFrameOutput(frame);
}

unsafe private void ProcessFrameOutput(AudioFrame frame)
{
    using (AudioBuffer buffer = frame.LockBuffer(AudioBufferAccessMode.Write))
    using (IMemoryBufferReference reference = buffer.CreateReference())
    {
        byte* dataInBytes;
        uint capacityInBytes;
        float* dataInFloat;

        // Get the buffer from the AudioFrame
        ((IMemoryBufferByteAccess)reference).GetBuffer(out dataInBytes, out capacityInBytes);

        dataInFloat = (float*)dataInBytes;

        List_db_For_FFT.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 32; i++)
        {
            List_db_For_FFT.Add(dataInFloat[i]);
        }
    }
}

private void SpectrumTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("List number: " + Number_Of_db_List.ToString());
    for (int a = 0; a <= List_db_For_FFT.Count -1; a++)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(List_db_For_FFT[a]);
    }
    Number_Of_db_List += 1;
}
```

As I wrote it I seem to be getting a little randomly in the sense the first 32 data (because it must be a power of 2) how can I correct it?

(I have not included FFT code because it is the next step I would like to understand how to pass the data correctly)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See the Matlab function.  The bandwidth is determined by the peak value(s) and the 3dB points around the peaks : https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/bandwidth.html

Comment: Sorry but reading the guide I can understand roughly but I can't apply it in reality. I really need an example ... If possible. Applied to the code I posted.

Comment: TRy this webpage : https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/powerbw.html

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand anything...